# Emploi du mot "secondement"

Tags: adverbes

> Les autres pistes du projet d'enseignement s'appuient premièrement sur les partenariats développés avec l'école d'ingénieurs Joe Smith et l'Université de Nulle Part et **secondement** sur le développement possible de l’internationalisation.

Peut-on employer l'adverbe *secondement* ? (registre soutenu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mot existe mais est désuet en France. Je déconseillerais donc de l'utiliser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What is this All next to searched word in NGram?

Comment: All cases (i.e. case insensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Oui il est possible d'utiliser l'adverbe *secondement* pour du registre soutenu:

***Étymologie***

> Dérivé de second, par son féminin seconde, avec le suffixe *-ment*.

***Adverbe***

> secondement:
>
> En second lieu.
>         Les quiétistes, qui rendent **premièrement** dans certains états la passiveté perpétuelle ; qui la rendent **secondement** fort commune et fort aisée, — (Jacques-Bénigne Bossuet, États d’oraisons X, 14. — cité par Littré)

**Synonymes**

> deuxièmement
>    secundo

Source: [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/secondement)